# Android Nativescript app crashing on start up

Tags: android, firebase, mobile, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm building a Nativescript app that will handle both the iOS and Android platforms. It's an app that uses bluetooth permissions, firebase, and it's targetSDK is 30 (due to Google Play Policy)

My app is crashing on start up, but ONLY ON ANDROID. I have no idea why and tns debug android outputs no message. My application id is the same across all my files. I’m not sure what to do. I tested the same code on an older Android running Android 8 and that worked fine. It's only on newer devices.

I'm wondering if it's something wrong with Android specific code, but I'm not sure what.

```
This issue may be caused by:
    * crash at startup (try `tns debug android --debug-brk` to check why it crashes)
    * different application identifier in your package.json and in your gradle files (check your identifier in `package.json` and in all *.gradle files in your App_Resources directory)
    * device is locked
    * manual closing of the application
Unable to apply changes on device: R58M50KS8YL. Error is: Application com.xxxxllc.xxxx is not running.
```

Here is my app.gradle, with my applicationId the same as in the nativescript.config.ts file and package.json file.

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxxxllc.xxxx"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    generatedDensities = []
  }
  aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
  }
}
```

`package.json`

```
"nativescript": {
    "id": "com.xxxxllc.xxxx"
  },
...
```

`nativescript.config.ts`

```
export default {
  id: 'com.xxxxllc.xxxx',
  appPath: 'src',
  appResourcesPath: 'App_Resources',
  android: {
    v8Flags: '--expose_gc',
    markingMode: 'none'
  }
} as NativeScriptConfig;
```

Full `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "~11.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.7",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.7",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.7",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.7",
    "@bradmartin/nativescript-urlhandler": "^2.0.1",
    "@mhtghn/nativescript-highcharts": "^1.0.2",
    "@nativescript-community/ble": "^3.0.25",
    "@nativescript-community/insomnia": "^2.0.2",
    "@nativescript-community/ui-drawer": "0.0.28",
    "@nativescript/angular": "~11.8.0",
    "@nativescript/core": "^8.0.8",
    "@nativescript/firebase": "^11.1.3",
    "@nativescript/theme": "~3.0.1",
    "@proplugins/nativescript-purchase": "^6.0.0",
    "@triniwiz/nativescript-toasty": "~4.1.3",
    "bluebird": "3.5.5",
    "crypto-es": "^1.2.7",
    "nativescript-permissions": "^1.3.11",
    "nativescript-sentry": "^2.0.1",
    "npm-check-updates": "^11.8.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.7",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.7",
    "@nativescript/android": "8.0.0",
    "@nativescript/ios": "8.0.0",
    "@nativescript/types": "~8.0.0",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "5.0.0-dev.5",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^11.2.14",
    "webpack": "5.48.0",
    "sass": "~1.35.1",
    "ts-node": "~10.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following fixed the crashing error on Android 11 phones:

Reducing `targetSDKVersion` to 29.

Changing `@nativescript/wepback` to `"5.0.0-rc.4"`.

Getting rid of `"webpack"`.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue before removing nativescript-sentry

Comment: Jacopo, this does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](/tour)